# Is it possible to remove status effects icons on top screen corner? [1.9]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'd like to disable the status effects icons on the top right corner of the screen, is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can make specific potion effects have no particles & hud but i don't know about all effects

Comment: If you are creating a map you can give the player no HUD potion effects

Comment: Have you tried drinking milk? :P

Comment: @angussidney i don't think he is trying to clear his effects, just make them not show on HUD

Comment: @ModDL It's called a joke. Hence the :P

Comment: @angussidney Oh my brain accidentally filtered that out.

Comment: It may be possible to edit your resource pack. This would mean, however, that effect _icons_ also wouldn't show up next to your inventory (the text should stay).

Comment: @1Darco1 hmm that could be an idea. I'll try it in case.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest versions, effects with showParticles = false don't show up in the hud.